# How can i create a crontab executing a specific link with auth token on Wordpress on Linux instance?

Tags: linux, wordpress, cron

i'm working to add a scheduled cron to my Linux instance but i'm getting error 403www.mywebsite.com.

The link that i need to ad as cron have a syntax like this:

```
curl https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/sync/launch.php?launch=ok&token=056319e12d2ea964aae027de4d1c9bed
```

When i try to curl or wget, i'm getting on console:

```
[error 403www.mysite.it
 [1]+  Done              curl https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/sync/launch.php?launch=ok
```

It's like the part of the link after **ok**, that contain the token, disappear. Maybe Linux are unable to read the character &?

What i've tried:

```
curl https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/sync/launch.php?launch=ok&token=056319e12d2ea964aae027de4d1c9bed
wget https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/sync/launch.php?launch=ok&token=056319e12d2ea964aae027de4d1c9bed
```

Also the same two line of code adding >/dev/null 2>&1 at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in double quotation mark. The symptom can be seen when curl URL is cut at ampersand character.

```
$ curl "your-URL"
$ curl "https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/plugins/sync/launch.php?launch=ok&token=056319e12d2ea964aae027de4d1c9bed"
```

Comment: it's amazing how simple the solution is. You literally saved my day. Thank you a lot, working like a charm.

Comment: Yes, the Linux things, space, etc you should put them between double quotation